# Working with site without API using python

Tags: python, web, sites

I want to work with site using python, but this site hasn't API

What can I do? I'm beginner in python, and i don't know how can I do this
Maybe I need to use python library "request"?
I really want to do this, but I don't know how

Comment: use requests or urllib, and if the site uses JavaScripts you can use Selnium or Playwright for instances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `requests` library to get html pages content.

1. Install

```
pip install requests
```

2. Example usage

```
import requests

example = requests.get("htpps://example.url")
print(example)
# You will receive html content
```